# BrokeredComponents TypeLoad and InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

We are trying to use BrokeredComponents on UWP. We are receiving either **TypeLoadException** or **InvalidCastException**.

We define expose a class called BrokeredComponentsHost that is used as a general class so we can access other classes inside BrokeredComponents.

We use GUIDs for each of the components.

Here is the BrokeredComponentsHost:

```
namespace BrokeredComponents
{    
    [Guid(BrokeredComponentsHost.ClassId), ComVisible(true)]
    public sealed class BrokeredComponentsHost : IBrokeredComponentFactory
    {
        internal const string ClassId = "881724C4-E330-40D5-BDA1-7D9F7C44FB7C";
        internal const string FactoryInterfaceId = "1FA85472-5B0D-487C-B58E-F8BE9A89D470";
        internal const string BarcodeScannerInterfaceId = "840F54D5-7AF7-4C31-91B0-BA274FCDD737";

        public string LastError { get; set; }

        public IPosScanner GetPosScanner()
        {
            return new PosScanner() { Host = this };
        }
    }

}
```

This is the IBrokeredComponentsFactory:

```
namespace BrokeredComponents
{
    [Guid(BrokeredComponentsHost.FactoryInterfaceId), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IBrokeredComponentFactory
    {
        IPosScanner GetPosScanner();
        string LastError { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the PosScanner and its interface:

```
namespace BrokeredComponents
{
    [Guid(BrokeredComponentsHost.BarcodeScannerInterfaceId), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IPosScanner : IPosDevice
    {
        bool DecodeData { get; set; }
        bool DeviceEnabled { get; set; }
        bool DataEventEnabled { get; set; }
        bool AutoDisable { get; set; }
        byte[] ScanData { get; }
    }
}
```

When we try to create a new Instance of BrokeredComponentsHost (`bcHost = new BrokeredComponents.BrokeredComponentsHost();`) it throws TypeLoadException.

If we define a new class (ex. ProcessExecutor Class), rebuild everything, then try to create a new instance of BrokeredComponentsHost again, it throws InvalidCastException instead.

We do **icacls . /T /grant “ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES”:RX** and **regsvr32 theproxy.dll**.

Has anyone encountered same problem and know the solution?

Thank you!

Edit: The exact error message I receive is `"Unable to cast COM object of type 'BrokeredComponents.BrokeredComponentsHost' to interface type 'BrokeredComponents.IBrokeredComponentFactory'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{1FA85472-5B0D-487C-B58E-F8BE9A89D470}' failed due to the following error: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."`

I am running on Windows 10 64-bit, but my BrokeredComponents project is Windows 8.1 and BrokeredComponentsProxy is VS 2013.

Edit 2: I have fixed the TypeLoad exception, it was an error with the Extensions for the exposed class not being defined in Appxmanifest file. I am still encountering InvalidCastException though.

Comment: >Class not registered    Have you rebuild the proxy stub project in VS as administrator? Looks like this is what this COM exception states

Comment: Have you added the correct winmd file to your references? There should be 2 winmd file, one of it should be added as reference to your project and the other one is implementation, it should always go where the proxy is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Franklin and Lawrence.

I have figure out the error, it was because the main UWP project was targeted towards x64 while our BrokeredComponents and other Projects in the solution are targeted for x86.

I changed UWP project to x86 and registered the .dll and now works perfectly.